# Regex - Replace only if the pattern is not inside a quote

Tags: php, regex

Lets say i want to write a regular expression to replace the word `Dog` with the word `Cat`.

e.g.

```
Dogs are scary.
```

will become:

```
Cats are scary.
```

But i want this regex to be applied only if the word Dog is not inside a quote.

e.g.

```
Dogs are scary but my mom told me that "Dogs are cute"
```

will become:

```
Cats are scary but my mom told me that "Dogs are cute"
```

I have no idea how to do it.
Help me please :)

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: In this specific example i use php but i think that it is irrelevant.

Comment: Offcourse it is relevent. The flavour of regex used in different languages are different. There are features that are not supported by some languages such as look behind for example

Comment: `regex` is not the most appropriate tool for this job. It can do it but the corresponding `regex` is complex and contains features that are not supported by all the languages that can handle `regex`. I would do it in two steps: first split the text in pieces that are enclosed in quotes or not (`regex` can do that) then use a simple string replacement function to do the change only in the pieces not enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for search:

```
(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)Dogs
```

And replace by:

```
Cats
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR8rI5/1)

It matches text only if outside quote -- i.e. match even number of quotes after keyword `dogs`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running perl or php you could use the below regex which uses the PCRE verb [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)

```
"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|Dog
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/24)

Then replace the matched `Dog` string with `Cat`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dogs(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Try this.Replace by `cat`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/25